# Insert an id from table A into table B if data is or isn't inserted into table A in mySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays

I've been coding for about a year now and currently I'm working on a portfolio piece (a recipe website) but I'm stuck and not sure how to proceed.

My problem is that I need to figure out a way to take the auto incremented id of the ingredient from table A whether inserted or not (if already in database) and insert it into table B.

When a recipe is submitted, I have my code set up so that it checks my ingredients table for the ingredient submitted using the following mySQL query.

```
SELECT 
        i.ingredient
    CASE
        WHEN 
            LOWER(?) = LOWER(ingredient) 
            THEN INSERT IGNORE INTO 
                i (ingredient) VALUES ?
        ELSE 
            LOWER(?) != LOWER(ingredient)
            THEN INSERT INTO
                i VALUES ?
    END
FROM
    ingredients i
```

I originally tried using an after insert trigger but realized that won't work if the ingredient is already in the database and not newly inserted. Because of this I think my approach may need to be refactored.

My goal is for when the recipe is submitted the ingredients are compiled into an array using:

```
let ingredients = req.body.ingredients;
    let ingredientArray = Array();
    ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        ingredientArray.push([ingredient.ingredient]);
    });
```

Then the mySQL query runs and either inserts the ingredient into table A or ignores if already present. Following either of those options then the auto incremented id of the ingredient is inserted into table B. To make it more complicated recipe_id would be pulled in from Table C (contains various other recipe information), amount would be the value typed in by the user into the input field (turned into an array), and unit_id would be a unit selected by the user which corresponds to a set predefined list of measurements already in the database (also turned into an array). Both of these arrays would use the same JavaScript code above to make them arrays.

Table A looks like:

| id | ingredient |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Sugar |
| 2 | Flour |

Table B looks like:

| id | recipe_id | amount | unit_id | ingredient_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 76 | 4 | 4 | 2 |

**UPDATED APPROACH**

Hopefully this is a better approach however, I'm stuck at figuring out how to get my if statement's false result to execute the `@checkIngredientFalse` followed by the `@checkIngredientTrue` since this will then add the ingredient `id` to the `recipe_ingredients` `ingredient_id` table column.

recipes.js

```
async function createRecipeIngredient(newRecipeId, ingredientName, unitId, amount) {
    let ingredients = req.body.ingredients;
    let ingredientArray = Array();
    ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
        ingredientArray.push([ingredient.ingredient]);
    });

const ingredientQuery = `
SET @checkIngredient = 
    (SELECT 
        i.id 
    FROM 
        ingredients i 
    WHERE 
        i.ingredient = LOWER(?)
    );

SET @newRecipeId = 
    (SELECT
        max(r.id)
    FROM
        recipes r
    );
    
SET @checkIngredientTrue = 
    (INSERT INTO
        recipeIngredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id)
    VALUES
        (@newRecipeId, @checkIngredient)
    );

SET @checkIngredientFalse = 
    (INSERT INTO 
        ingredients (ingredient) 
    VALUES 
        (LOWER(?))
    
    //MISSING CODE HERE//

    );

IF(@checkIngredient, @checkIngredientTrue, @checkIngredientFalse);`

const [_queryRows, _queryFields] = await db.promise().query(ingredientQuery, [newRecipeId, _ingredientName, _unitId, _amount]);

module.exports = { getRecipe, getRecipeComments, getRecipePhotos, getUserRecipeCommentLikes, createRecipe, insertRecipePhoto, createRecipeIngredient };
```

routerRecipes.js

```
router.post('/recipes/new', cloudinary.upload.single('photo'), async (req, res, _next) => {
    await recipeQueries.createRecipe();
    await recipeQueries.insertRecipePhoto(newRecipeId, req.user, req.file.path);
    await recipeQueries.createRecipeIngredient(newRecipeId);

    res.redirect('/recipes');
});
```

Comment: Check if the ingredient is already in the table. If it is, use its `id` in the `ingredient_id` field of the recipe. If not, insert it in the ingredient table, then use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the ID of the new ingredient, and use that in the `ingredient_id`.

Comment: `ingredientQuery` only has one placeholder, but you're supplying 4 values.

Comment: My intention is to eventually do this same process with both a measurement and unit in conjunction with the ingredient when a recipe is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each ingredient in the recipe:

- `SELECT id FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient = ?`
- If the above query succeeds, set `ingredient_id` to the returned id
- If not, do `INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient) VALUES (?)`, and set `ingredient_id` to the auto increment ID that was assigned
- `INSERT INTO recipes` using the value of `ingredient_id` found with the above steps.

```
ingredients.forEach(async (ingredient) => {
    let ingredient_id;
    const [ing_ids] = await db.promise().query("SELECT id FROM ingredients WHERE ingredient = ?", [ingredient.toLowerCase()]);
    if (ing_ids.length > 0) {
        ingredient_id = ing_ids[0][0];
    } else {
        const res = await db.promise().query("INSERT INTO ingredients (ingredient) VALUES (?)", [ingredient]);
        ingredient_id = res.insertId;
    }
    await db.promise().query("INSERT INTO recipeIngredients (recipe_id, ingredient_id) VALUES (?, ?)", [recipe_id, ingredient_id]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I updated my approach within the question and made an edit. I'm closer to reaching my answer however I not sure how to best proceed. What do you think?

Comment: Can you show your actual JavaScript that executes the prepared statements with values?

Comment: I added in my in the JavaScript, recipes.js contains the mySQL queries and routerRecipes.js is the router. I hope that's helpful!

Comment: I've added the JavaScript.

Comment: I'll try implementing that with how I've set up my code and get back once done.